# Create file in Linux and replace content

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a project in Linux. I want to create a file named `index.html` in all folders.
So I have used the following command:

```
find . -type d -exec touch {}/index.html \;
```

It's working! Now I'm trying to copy the existing file from a given location and it to be automatically replaced into all the folders of my project.

Answer (score 1):

This should actually work exactly in the same way:

```
find . -type d -exec cp $sourcedir/index.html {}/index.html \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to copy a given file in all the directories.

You can use a similar `find` command :

```
find . -type d -exec cp -f /tmp/index.html {} \;
```

where `/tmp/index.html` is path to the original file (replace it with your own path).

Also, you don't need to create the files if your final objective is to replace them with the original file.

Comment: You must escape those `{` char-pairs.

Comment: @Zsolt: Worked perfectly well on my ubuntu. Please try and see if it works for you.

Comment: My bad. For some strange reason, I used to think it must be escaped, and did not checked the docs. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -cvzf index.tar.gz `find . -type f -iname 'index.html'` && scp index.tar.gz USER@SERVER:/your/projec/root/on/SERVER && ssh USER@SERVER "tar -xvzf index.tar.gz"
```

Or if you're in the proper directory localhost, and `rsync` is available:

```
rsync -r --exclude='**' --include='**/index.html' . USER@SERVER:/your/projec/root/on/SERVER
```

HTH